# no matching call for ann->train( TrainData, trainClasses, weights );

Tags: c++, opencv

hello i am still beginner about opencv and qt, i am confused with my line

```
/OCR.cpp:332: error: no matching function for call to 'cv::ml::ANN_MLP::train(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)'
     ann->train( TrainData, trainClasses, weights)
```

this is my program

```
void OCR::train(Mat TrainData, Mat classes, int nlayers){
    Mat layers(1,3,CV_32SC1);
    layers.at<int>(0)= TrainData.cols;
    layers.at<int>(1)= nlayers;
    layers.at<int>(2)= numCharacters;
//    ann.create(layers, cv::ml::ANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM, 1, 1);
    ann->setLayerSizes(layers);
        ann->setActivationFunction(cv::ml::ANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM, 1, 1);

    //Prepare trainClases
    //Create a mat with n trained data by m classes
    Mat trainClasses;
    trainClasses.create( TrainData.rows, numCharacters, CV_32FC1 );
    for( int i = 0; i <  trainClasses.rows; i++ )
    {
        for( int k = 0; k < trainClasses.cols; k++ )
        {
            //If class of data i is same than a k class
            if( k == classes.at<int>(i) )
                trainClasses.at<float>(i,k) = 1;
            else
                trainClasses.at<float>(i,k) = 0;
        }
    }
    Mat weights( 1, TrainData.rows, CV_32FC1, Scalar::all(1) );

    //Learn classifier
    ann->train( TrainData, trainClasses, weights );
    trained=true;
   //trained = ann->train(TrainData, trainClasses, weights);
//trained = ann->train(TrainData, ROW_SAMPLE, weights);
    }
```

can everybody tell me how to solve this? i also have problem in the ROW_SAMPLE not found even i have included ml.hpp. sorry for my english, thanks

Comment: `cv::ml::ROW_SAMPLE`

Comment: As for the other problem there is no version of `train` that takes three `Mat` arguments, which is exactly what the error message is telling you. Not sure why you expected it to work.

Comment: ah okay that's why the train is not working, thanks